# Insertion Sort Running Time Complexity

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computational-complexity, sorting

In the worst case, $j$ comparisons are required to insert the $jth$ element into the correct position. For the insertion sort algorithm, the running time complexity would be $\mathcal{\Theta}(n^2)$ for the number of comparisons as follows:

$$2+3+\textit{...}+n=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}-1$$

**Question**: Why the number of comparisons start from $2$ above although I think it should start from $1+2+3\textit{...}$?
[image]

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: @TravisJ. I did not formulate the question well. I meant why the number of comparisons start from $2$ not $1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause it does it twice. First it asks: is $a_2>a_1,$ the answer is yes, then it does $i=i+1,$ so $i=2$ now and then it asks $a_2>a_2.$ is false and it breaks. 
As you see there were two comparisions.